# Как выполняются проверки при использовании Imagick

Tags: php

Имеется такой код:

```
<form action="/admin/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="img">
.......
$this->model->productUploadImage($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $id);
.....
public function productUploadImage($path, $id) 
{
    $img = new Imagick($path);
    $img->cropThumbnailImage(1080, 600);
    $img->setImageCompressionQuality(80);
    $img->writeImage('public/materials/'.$id.'.jpg');
}
```

Передаю через ajax текст, но при передаче картинки в функцию `productUploadImage`  что то идет не так. Как проверить правильный ли путь у картинки, выполнились эти функции или нет.

Comment: `try { /* ваш код */ } catch (\ImagickException $e) { var_dump($e);}`

Comment: @Deonis у меня var_dump, echo alert не работают, наверно из за того, что страница не перезагружается. Т.е. я с /admin/add отправляю /admin/add

Comment: Делайте вывод в файл:
`try { /* ваш код */ } catch (\ImagickException $e) { 
    file_put_contents('error.log', var_export($e,1));
}`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, в catch не зашел код, но определил, что проблема здесь $img = new Imagick($path);

Comment: путь к картинке выбираю такой Z:\2112331.JPG, в а $path содержится Z:\tmp\php1D20.tmp так и должно быть?

Comment: попробовал в index перенести потестить выдало ошибку Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found добавил use Imagick; все равно осталась. Может быть у меня просто нету этого класса?

Comment: Посмотрите `phpinfo()`, там будет видно - есть ImageMagick или нет. Если не окажется, то [установите это расширение](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.installation.php).  Класс в глобальном пространстве, т.е. `new \Imagick($path);`

Comment: @Deonis вроде бы есть usr\local\ImageMagick;